# Can't open virtual terminal for client LPARs in Ubuntu 20.04 for PowerPC

Tags: command-line, power-management, ibm

**Environment:** IBM POWER server virtualized with NovaLink on Ubuntu 20.04.6.

**The issue:** Cannot open virtual terminal to the user LPARS (VMs). The drmgr is failing with the following error:

```
########## May 03 05:29:48 2023 ##########
drmgr: -c slot -s U8284.22A.21279DW-V1-C7 -a -w 3
Validating I/O DLPAR capability...yes.
Getting node types 0x00000003
Could not find DRC property group in path: /proc/device-tree/vdevice.
Could not find DRC property group in path: /proc/device-tree/pci@80000002000001b.
There are no DR capable slots on this system
Could not find DRC property group in path: /proc/device-tree.
Could not find drc index for U8284.22A.21279DW-V1-C7, unable to add theslot.
########## May 03 05:29:48 2023 ##########
```

However, the system capabilities seem correct:

```
$ sudo drmgr --capabilities
Validating CPU DLPAR capability...yes.
Validating Memory DLPAR capability...yes.
Validating I/O DLPAR capability...yes.
Validating PHB DLPAR capability...yes.
Validating HEA DLPAR capability...no.
    stat("/sys/bus/ibmebus/probe"): No such file or directory
Validating partition migration capability...yes.
Validating partition hibernation capability...yes.
cpu_dlpar=yes,mem_dlpar=yes,slot_dlpar=yes,phb_dlpar=yes,hea_dlpar=no,pmig=yes,cpu_entitlement=yes,mem_entitlement=yes,slb_resize=yes,phib=yes
```

What could be the root cause and the possible resolution?

Comment: From your question please explain what this line means. What could be the RC and the possible resolution?